# Can enemies see the pets of invisible heroes?

Tags: dota-2

The International Compendium 2015 grants Almond the Frondillo at level 50. This pet can be equipped by a limited range of heroes, including Riki.

If I am invisible as Riki (or anyone else), will my pet be visible to the enemy team, thus revealing that I'm nearby?

Comment: Unionhawk..really?  please show some guts and help me by giving answer but not the editing of few spaces in text..

Comment: I am just trying to help by making formatting changes. I am not qualified to answer questions about Dota 2, but I am qualified to make formatting edits.

Comment: ok thanx but you are helping by removing few spaces? Ask yourself please..anyway thanx..sorry for my hard words..:(

Comment: I think the question here is "If I have a pet and I turn invisible, will the pet still be visible to the enemy?", is that correct?

Comment: @pyritie no as there are no more pet in dota 2 but only this one and with cm.

Comment: @Leothelion technically Pyritie is right. If I have a shadowblade on my CrystalMaiden, would it work the same ? So a more generic question could be good here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for Almond the Frondillo on the wiki you'll find that it's a **[Summoned Unit](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Summoned_Unit)** and the wiki says:

> Enemy players cannot see summoned units unless they have vision of its
>   owner

So **No** they cant see Almond the Frondillo when you're invisible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer,,m really fool that i din get this..:)